# how to send sms to python script?

Tags: python, gps, sms, twilio

I am developing a python script that will find the LAtitude and Longitude of a particular location and store it in a text file . The location will be sent through an SMS to the python script .I can do the later part of finding the latitude and longitude using 'geocode' library in python , but i'm not sure as to how to accept the data from SMS .

I have worked with the TWILIO module previously and i know how to Send SMS via Python script to a phone number using it . But I want to know the process of receiving SMS message sent from a phone number and then using that message body in the python script for further operation .

This is how I have been sending SMS to phone numbers -

```
import os
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
accountSID = '****'
authToken = '***'
twilioCli = TwilioRestClient(accountSID, authToken)
myTwilioNumber = '+1 ***'
myCellPhone = '+***'
message = twilioCli.messages.create(body=string, from_=myTwilioNumber,  to=myCellPhone)
```

If you can provide a solution to do the opposite of the above process i.e receive an SMS instead of sending it , through TWILIO service , itll be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with Twilio, then you can also use it to receive short messages. Just register a number (this will be our receiver) and add webhook in `Messaging` -> `A message comes in` section. Your webhook is an end-point which implements getting messages on `POST` action. Then you can [process received messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/sms/how-to-receive-and-reply-in-python) as you want.

You can find a detailed tutorial on [official website](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/how-to-receive-and-respond-to-a-text-message-with-python-flask-and-twilio.html).

**Edit:**

**What is the flow?**

1. You prepare an application (in tutorial - implemented in flask). You have to run it on application server. Your domain is, for example, john-smith.com.
2. You register an end-point as webhook. Your end-point is john-smith.com/sms.
3. You send a short message to your number registered in Twilio.
4. When the short messages come, it's handled by Twilio and sent as `POST` request to your application **to URL specified as webhook**.

This is **your** python code (a [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) application) from tutorial. This is the place where you extract number and message. This is also your application.

> ```
> from flask import Flask, request 
> from twilio import twiml
>
> app = Flask(__name__)
>
> @app.route('/sms', methods=['POST']) 
> def sms():
>     number = request.form['From']
>     message_body = request.form['Body']
>
>     resp = twiml.Response()
>     resp.message('Hello {}, you said: {}'.format(number, message_body))
>     return str(resp)   
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     app.run()
> ```

A `message_body` variable is received message of SMS. You can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I am a bit confused with that webhook part . what do i specify there ? Also once i add the required parameters in the webhook section , how do i extract it in my python code ? any sample examples will be appreciated.

Comment: @johnsmith Hello, I have edited an answer, is it clean now? :)

Comment: Thanks this helps . I'll update incase of any problems .

Answer (score 1):

A simple code for sms sending in Python:

```
from smsapi import SmsApi

apikey = "675031878xxxxxxxxx" sender = "SEDEMO"

sms = SmsApi(apikey, sender)

sms = sms.send_sms(

recipient="902000xxxx",

message="test message"

)
```

Make sure you have copied **`smsapi.py` class file** from https://github.com/spring-edge/ Github repository and placed in same directory. In above code recipient is the destination mobile number and sms body as message.